# Solid purple colour appears when trying to view large files in Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, graphics, adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to do some editing of large uncompressed .tif files (800MB-3.5GB).
While I'm able to open them in Adobe Photoshop and Bridge, I am having real trouble opening the images in Preview as the picture begins to resolve on opening and then suddenly turns purple! Below are two images of the solid colour wiping across the image as it resolves from left to right.
[image: Image partially covered]
[image: Image fully covered]

- I've checked the images to see if they contain an alpha channel which
  Preview would normally recognise as a mask. None of the images have
  an alpha channel.
- I have isolated the layers in photoshop to extract the image from any baked in alpha channels and exported them. The issue still occurs.
- I have reformatted the image to .PNG, the issue still
  occurs.
- I have compressed the image using LZW and the issue still
  occurs.

I have contacted the person who took the images to get new copies to see if the versions I have are corrupted in some way as opening them in Adobe Reader comes up with this message:

[image: Error message]

The images do open well in Windows Image Viewer and Irfanview however which makes me suspect that the images aren't corrupted.

I'm less inclined to think that the issue is something to do with the size of the image as the smaller .PNG and compressed .tif files also have the issue. Preview seems to have an issue with only a select few files that I am working on. Opening similarly sized .tif files from previous batches does not yield the same result in Preview.

Currently running OSX 10.15.4 on a 2017 iMac 3.4GHz i5, 64GB 2400 MHz DDR4 with a Radeon Pro 570 4GB.

**Is this an issue that anyone else has encountered using preview before and does anyone know what causes it? Better yet, is there a solution?**

The ultimate goal is to have these images uploaded in an online archive for students so making these images compatible for any operating system (if that is the problem) would be the best outcome.

Cheers,

K.

Comment: Have you tried Adobe Reader?  You could maybe use that instead. Its free.

Comment: As mentioned above, I've tried Adobe Acrobat Reader already.

Comment: Acrobat doesn't open tiff files. (At best, it might convert them to PDF before opening.)
Is purple your selection colour in Preview? Open a smaller image and press Command A.

Comment: Purple isn't my selection colour. Opening a smaller image and pressing Command A doesn't yield the same result. I have no selection colour simply a selection square. Thanks for clarifying about Adobe, yes I had in fact meant to convert these .tif files to PDF.

Comment: How do they appear in Safari?

Comment: I've opened the file in Safari. I've left it open for about 10 mins. It opens fine. I'm unsure as to why, and there are no clear signs in the file about which images need to be opened with Safari and which ones need to be opened with Preview.